# border-radius.htc makes border rounded, but not image

Tags: internet-explorer-7, behavior, css

I'm using [border-radius.htc](https://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/downloads/detail?name=border-radius.htc), trying to make round corners in IE7. It's partially working, the border gets rounded corners, but not the image, resulting in a round border behind a square image.

```
<div id="container">
 <ul>
  <li>

    <img src="test.png">

  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
#container {
   position:relative;
   top: -20px;
   width:1000px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-left:-10px;
}

#container li {
   float:left; 
   list-style:none; 
   margin: 0 5px; 
 }

#container ul li {
  width:180px; 
  height:200px;
}

#container ul li img {
   width:175px; 
   height:175px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 999px;
   -moz-border-radius: 999px;
   border-radius: 999px;
   border: solid 3px #fff; 
   behavior: url(.../css/border-radius.htc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden;` for images

```
#container ul li img {
   width:175px; 
   height:175px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 999px;
   -moz-border-radius: 999px;
   border-radius: 999px;
   border: solid 3px #fff; 
   behavior: url(.../css/border-radius.htc);
   overflow: hidden; 
}
```

The reason you have to do this is so then the corners of the images that are, in theory, overflowing from the div, are hidden.

Comment: Your image is 175px square and the radius is 999px?